# Java 2D Tile based game rotated by 45 degrees?

Tags: java, 2d

I am working on a 2D tile based game which has all tiles rotated by 45 degrees.
I want to do this:

[image]
[image]

The reason is to create a different angle of look at the 2D game.

There are quite a lot of tutorials for tile based games but I don't know about any with rotated tiles like this.

So my question is: How to create tiles rotated by 45 degrees? I would appreciate any code or links.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I am using Java Graphics2D, not OpenGL

Comment: It's not exactly what you are looking try looking for isometric tile game tutorials. It will get you on the right track.

Comment: No, I am not using OpenGL. And thanks for the tip about isometric tile game.

Answer (score 0):

example of how to rotate your graphics:

```
paint(Graphics2D g) {
  g.translate(component.width / 2, component.height / 2);
  g.rotate(myRotation); //note: The rotation parameter must be in radians
  g.translate(-component.width / 2, -component.height / 2);
  //now paint the component as you normally would
  //Note: Rotation may cause you to try to paint outside of the *bounds* of the component. You must make allowances for this
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not really what I am looking for. I know its possible to rotate Graphics, but it rotates only visually, but it would still require to somehow calculate positions for objects on tiles etc.

Comment: @Ladas125 possible to do by rotating the event click by -rotation, and determining the correct square that way. If you have subcomponents catching the event within the rotated component, this won't work